# Cannot draw graph with many nodes in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams, pst-tree

Here is the LaTeX code generated by a package

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{article}
         \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree,geometry}
         \usepackage{lscape}
         \pagestyle{empty}
         \newcommand{\Tbox}[1]{\Tr{\psframebox{#1}}}
         \begin{document}
         \begin{landscape}
         \begin{center}
         \psset{tnsep=2pt,tnheight=0cm,treesep=.01cm,levelsep=1pt,radius=50pt}
         \pstree{\Tcircle{    1}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{AdmitTier}\\$\in S_{    1}$}}}{
        \pstree{\Tcircle{    2}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{ETHNICITY}\\$\in S_{    2}$}}}{
           \Tbox{    4}~[tnpos=b]{$     64/    343$}
           \pstree{\Tcircle{    5}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{AdmitTier}\\$\in S_{    5}$}}}{
              \pstree{\Tcircle{   10}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{ETHNICITY}\\$\in S_{   10}$}}}{
                 \pstree{\Tcircle{   20}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{EstimateTu}\\$\leq    0.807E+04$}}}{
                    \Tbox{   40}~[tnpos=b]{$   1483/   4386$}
                    \Tbox{   41}~[tnpos=b]{$    266/    898$}
                 }
                 \pstree{\Tcircle{   21}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{GPA}\\$\leq     2.30    $}}}{
                    \pstree{\Tcircle{   42}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{AdmitTier}\\$\in S_{   42}$}}}{
                       \pstree{\Tcircle{   84}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{ACT}\\$\leq     17.0    $}}}{
                          \Tbox{  168}~[tnpos=b]{$     77/    260$}
                          \Tbox{  169}~[tnpos=b]{$     74/    148$}
                       }
                       \pstree{\Tcircle{   85}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{GPA}\\$\leq     2.00    $}}}{
                          \pstree{\Tcircle{  170}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{GPA}\\$\leq     1.80    $}}}{
                             \Tbox{  340}~[tnpos=b]{$     78/    332$}
                             \Tbox{  341}~[tnpos=b]{$    124/    259$}
                          }
                          \Tbox{  171}~[tnpos=b]{$    312/    591$}
                       }
                    }
                    \pstree{\Tcircle{   43}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{AdmitTier}\\$\in S_{   43}$}}}{
                       \Tbox{   86}~[tnpos=b]{$    411/   1128$}
                       \pstree{\Tcircle{   87}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{ETHNICITY}\\$\in S_{   87}$}}}{
                          \pstree{\Tcircle{  174}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{GPA}\\$\leq     2.90    $}}}{
                             \Tbox{  348}~[tnpos=b]{$    531/   1122$}
                             \Tbox{  349}~[tnpos=b]{$    317/    839$}
                          }
                          \Tbox{  175}~[tnpos=b]{$     63/    110$}
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
              \pstree{\Tcircle{   11}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{EstimateTu}\\$\leq    0.753E+04$}}}{
                 \pstree{\Tcircle{   22}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{ETHNICITY}\\$\in S_{   22}$}}}{
                    \pstree{\Tcircle{   44}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{AdmitTier}\\$\in S_{   44}$}}}{
                       \Tbox{   88}~[tnpos=b]{$   1117/   2498$}
                       \Tbox{   89}~[tnpos=b]{$     98/    168$}
                    }
                    \Tbox{   45}~[tnpos=b]{$    164/    306$}
                 }
                 \pstree{\Tcircle{   23}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{GPA}\\$\leq     2.80    $}}}{
                    \Tbox{   46}~[tnpos=b]{$    285/    611$}
                    \Tbox{   47}~[tnpos=b]{$    527/   1364$}
                 }
              }
           }
        }
        \pstree{\Tcircle{    3}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{AdmitTier}\\$\in S_{    3}$}}}{
           \pstree{\Tcircle{    6}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{ETHNICITY}\\$\in S_{    6}$}}}{
              \Tbox{   12}~[tnpos=b]{$    124/    317$}
              \Tbox{   13}~[tnpos=b]{$   2652/   5179$}
           }
           \pstree{\Tcircle{    7}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{ETHNICITY}\\$\in S_{    7}$}}}{
              \pstree{\Tcircle{   14}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{Underrep}\\$\in S_{   14}$}}}{
                 \pstree{\Tcircle{   28}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{GPA}\\$\leq     2.90    $}}}{
                    \Tbox{   56}~[tnpos=b]{$     38/     84$}
                    \Tbox{   57}~[tnpos=b]{$     45/    127$}
                 }
                 \pstree{\Tcircle{   29}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{ACT}\\$\leq     17.0    $}}}{
                    \Tbox{   58}~[tnpos=b]{$    521/    870$}
                    \Tbox{   59}~[tnpos=b]{$    520/    910$}
                 }
              }
              \pstree{\Tcircle{   15}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{ETHNICITY}\\$\in S_{   15}$}}}{
                 \pstree{\Tcircle{   30}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{EstimateTu}\\$\leq    0.753E+04$}}}{
                    \pstree{\Tcircle{   60}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{GPA}\\$\leq     2.90    $}}}{
                       \pstree{\Tcircle{  120}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{ACT}\\$\leq     18.0    $}}}{
                          \pstree{\Tcircle{  240}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{GPA}\\$\leq     2.60    $}}}{
                             \pstree{\Tcircle{  480}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{GPA}\\$\leq     2.30    $}}}{
                                \Tbox{  960}~[tnpos=b]{$    141/    238$}
                                \Tbox{  961}~[tnpos=b]{$    140/    197$}
                             }
                             \Tbox{  481}~[tnpos=b]{$    153/    225$}
                          }
                          \Tbox{  241}~[tnpos=b]{$    805/   1266$}
                       }
                       \Tbox{  121}~[tnpos=b]{$   2113/   3566$}
                    }
                    \pstree{\Tcircle{   61}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{ACT}\\$\leq     23.0    $}}}{
                       \Tbox{  122}~[tnpos=b]{$   1153/   1905$}
                       \Tbox{  123}~[tnpos=b]{$    686/   1248$}
                    }
                 }
                 \pstree{\Tcircle{   31}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{GPA}\\$\leq     2.80    $}}}{
                    \Tbox{   62}~[tnpos=b]{$    240/    341$}
                    \Tbox{   63}~[tnpos=b]{$    441/    694$}
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }    
       \end{center}
         \caption{LOTUS tree: Intermediate and terminal nodes are represented by
         circles and squares, respectively. The number inside a node is the
         node label and the splitting rule of an intermediate node is given
         beside it. If a case satisfies the rule, it goes to the left child node;
         otherwise the right child node. The ratio of cases with Y=1 to the
         node sample size is given beneath each terminal node.}
         \end{landscape}
         \end{document}
```

I changed some parameters in the line:

```
psset{tnsep=2pt,tnheight=0cm,treesep=.01cm,levelsep=1pt,radius=50pt}
```

but still cannot see the whole graph.
Please help, thanks

Answer (score 2):

it is too big and your setting makes no sense. Use

```
[...]
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[p!]
%\psset{tnsep=2pt,tnheight=0cm,treesep=.01cm,levelsep=1pt,radius=50pt}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%%%%%%%%%   SCALE it down
  \pstree{\Tcircle{    1}~[tnpos=l]{\shortstack[r]{\texttt{AdmitTier}\\$\in S_{    1}$}}}{%

[ ... ]   the tree stuff

              }%
           }%
        }%
}%
}    
\caption{LOTUS tree: Intermediate and terminal nodes are represented by
   circles and squares, respectively. The number inside a node is the
   node label and the splitting rule of an intermediate node is given
   beside it. If a case satisfies the rule, it goes to the left child node;
   otherwise the right child node. The ratio of cases with Y=1 to the
    node sample size is given beneath each terminal node.}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
[...]
```

[image]